# How to open Page1.xaml into MainWindow.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I have what should be a very simple desktop application I'm working on but I'm having issues doing a few basic tasks. I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

I have created a project from a blank WPF template. I created a new Page, named Page1.xaml, to go along with the default MainWindow.xaml Window.

In my MainWindow.xaml window I have Grid and inside the grid is an Image.

```
<Grid MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown_1" Cursor="Hand" >
    <Image Name="ImageIntro" Source="images/Stories-intro.jpg" Stretch="None" />
</Grid>
```

The Grid has a MouseDown event so that I can detect when a user clicks anywhere inside the Grid.

```
private void Grid_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Pretty basic and that all works and compiles as intended.

The issue I have is that I'm unable to load the Page1.xaml inside my window on MainWindow.xaml. I don't want to open a separate window, I just want the content on Page1.xaml to be displayed inside the visible window of MainWindow.xaml.

I tried using the following but I get an error when I click the on my link: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred

```
private void Grid_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        NavigationService ns = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
        ns.Navigate(uri);            
    }
```

This is not a browser application, it's simply a desktop application. The first screen (MainWindow.xaml) should just click thru to display the second screen (Page1.xaml).

I want the Page1.xaml content to take up the entire Window of MainWindow.xaml (sorry, but I can't stress that enough, I don't want a frame or any content from MainWindow.xaml showing when the user is on Page1.xaml).

I'm pretty new to Desktop apps but I have extensive knowledge with .Net C# for web applications. I'm not against changing the flow of what I have if there's a better way to accomplish this. For example, perhaps I shouldn't be using a Window to Page navigation and should instead use a Window to Window or something else.

I would imagine this would be a relatively simple task, but I haven't found anything that works yet so hopefully someone on here can explain it.

Comment: I don't remember GetNavigationService() to require any parameters

Comment: if I remove "this" from GetNavigationService(), then the code doesn't compile.

Comment: @FilippoB https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.getnavigationservice(v=vs.110).aspx  Takes a `DependencyObject` as a parameter.

Comment: That doesn't really help me, is there any sample code that just shows navigating to a page in action? Sure it seems I'm missing a key element like a frame or navigationwindow but I have no idea how to implement it. Like I said, navigating to a new page from a window shouldn't be a complicated task and yet I see no example on that page showing how to do it.

Comment: I think I understand this a bit more now, my NavigationService ns was returning null...but why exactly? Am I missing an element on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a frame in Main Window

> then in your event hander

```
  Page1 mypage=new Page1();//object of the page 1

  frame.Navigate(mypage);//pass it to frame navigate method
```

Comment: Thanks, you and CodingGorilla pointed me in the right direction. I added a frame to MainWindow.xaml (inside the Grid tags <Frame Name="Frame1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>) and then on the event I used Page1 mypage = new Page1();
            Frame1.Navigate(mypage);

Comment: you are welcome if the above answer has help you please mark it accept
as it will help some body else :)

Answer (score 1):

Read this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.getnavigationservice(v=vs.110).aspx) link, the requirements for that to work say that `this` (in your code) must be a `Frame`.  I don't see any XAML code here, but I'm guessing `this` is a Window.  You need a frame to host the navigation, so your `MainWindow` should probably *just* the frame, and the contents of your current window should be "Page0".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Everyone who helped, here is the solution I used (I wanted to make sure a code example was here for anyone who has this same issue in the future).

I added a Frame to my MainWindow.xaml page:

```
<Grid MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown_1" Cursor="Hand" >
    <Image Name="ImageIntro" Source="images/Stories-intro.jpg" Stretch="None" />
    <Frame Name="Frame1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

Then I added the following to my event:

```
private void Grid_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Page1 mypage = new Page1();
        Frame1.Navigate(mypage);
    }
```

This allowed me to click on my link and the new page, Page1.xaml appeared. There was also a navigation bar that appeared at the top and the content didn't completely take up the MainWindow.xaml window but I think I can fiddle around with the settings and get it to where I want it.

Much thanks to Filippo B, Nauman Ahmad, and CodingGorilla for the assist.